# Rails 5 form for submitting array passed as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a serialized Array field in my model called `:cords`, and part of my form looks like so:

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
    ....
    <p>
        <%= f.label :cords %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :cords, name: "group[cords][]" %>
    </p>
    ....
```

Then inside my controller, I attempt to use it like so

```
    @group = Group.new(params.require(:group).permit(:name, :members, cords: [] ))

    if @group.save
        redirect_to @group
    else
        render 'new'
    end
```

This doesn't seem to work though, because when I type in some array like `[[1,2],[3,4]]` I see the SQL insert is

```
INSERT INTO "groups" ("cords", "name", "members", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cords", "---\n- \"[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]\"\n"], ["name", "GG"], ["members", 55], ["created_at", "2017-06-12 02:13:37.462355"], ["updated_at", "2017-06-12 02:13:37.462355"]]
```

Why is `cords` submitted as `["cords", "---\n- \"[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]\"\n"]`? I believe I'm doing something wrong with my actual form setup

Comment: Which database management are you using?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Default that comes with rails5.1?

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support array columns type, see the [datatypes](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in the version 3, most probably youll need Postgresql.

Comment: I would be very eager to see the `params` that are coming in the server log.

Comment: try this `<%= f.text_field "group[cords][]" %>` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation of problem:

Rails serialized column indeed allow us to store complex data types such as array, but they do so in YAML format by default.
What you do is pass a text as `group[cords][]` param.
So, what you should get in your `params` is `{group: {cords: [ "[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]" ]}}`. Take notice, **that `cords` is array of one element, which is string you pass to it**: `"[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]"`

That array gets serialized in compliance with YAML scalar syntax: `"---\n- \"[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]\"\n"`. Let's look at it up close, first substituting newlines:

```
---
- "[[1,2],[3,4],[5.5,6]]"
#here also newline
```

Three hyphens indicate start of YAML document.

Array is packed like this:

```
- "first_element"
- "second_element"
- "third_element"
```

Is equal to `["first_element", "second_element", "third_element"]`

Backslash before quotation marks just escape those in SQL denoting that quotes are part of the string.

So, as you can see, rails do just what it is supposed / you told it to do: *it gets single string as one element of array and it stores one element of array, containing that string.*

## Solution:

What you should do if you still want to get user input as array is transform that manually.

- Drop the `[]` in `text_field`: `f.text_field :cords, name:
  "group[cords]"`
- In controller, transform that text into ruby array, for example like this:

```rb
def cords_to_a
  # get the params[:group][:cords], if it's empty use empty array string
  cords = params.dig(:group, :cords).presence || "[]"
  # parse it, possibly you also want to handle parse exceptions
  # and transform parsed array as something else
  # also, user will be able to save any json object
  # to your serialized field, and it will be parsed
  # accordingly: either to array or to hash
  JSON.parse cords
end

def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :members).merge({cords: cords_to_a})
end
```

and after that use `Group.new(group_params)`

**Take notice:** you still will get a "strange" string in your `INSERT` statement, because that will contain YAML-encoded array: essentially, a string.

## Further reading:

- [YAML syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html)
- [Rails serialized fields source with doc](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/99820fbeb29ae35a7771f3991bd119b102861aa7/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb#L48)

Comment: Awesome answer! When my question becomes eligible, I'm going to give you a bounty for going into such detail.

Comment: You absolutely nailed it!